# Как запретить многим пользователям пользоваться одним ключем доступа?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, безопасность, password

Есть сайт, где ключ доступа дает возможность использовать больше функций, но проблема в том, что пользователи могут использовать один ключ доступа на многих.

Есть ли способы это предотвратить ?

Comment: О каком ключе доступа идет речь?

Comment: Единственный реальный способ - делать ключ физическим, в виде USB-брелка, с асимметричной криптографией и невозможностью извлечь приватный ключ из него

Comment: Речь идет о цифровом ключе доступа

Comment: @andreymal доступных не извлекаемых брелков на рынке нет, да и работать с ними через браузер практически не реально)

Comment: @ArnoDorian ну а цифровой ключ в любом случае можно неограниченно копировать. (В ответе eri предложил более-менее работающий вариант с одноразовым временным ключом, но в зависимости от задачи при желании можно докопаться и до него тоже)

Comment: @eri а что же U2F? Какая с ними проблема?

Comment: U2F - это 50 баксов @RomanKonoval

Answer (score 1):

Используй этот ключ (PSK) для получения временного ключа, сохраняй в браузере только его. Авторизацию всю проходи по временному ключу. Если вводишь PSK на другом браузере делай не действительным старый временный ключ (самое простое это переписать его значение в базе на другое). Так авторизация перейдет из одного браузера в другой.

Если можно сдеать ключ одноразовым - то нужно сделать его одноразовым.

Защитить временный ключ от копирования просто. Сохраняем его в куки (или в хидер - смотря на чем фронтэнд), а на сервере перезаписываем временный ключик при каждом запросе через мидлваре.

Comment: Что мешает скопировать временный ключ?

Comment: Проще просто прямо запретить больше одной сессии и привязывать каждую сессию к IP. Меньше танцев, результат надежней. Но это не запрещает пользоваться ключом нескольким пользователям в разное время.

Comment: @RomanKonoval пользователю будет очень больно в среде с динамическим IP-адресом

Comment: привязка сессии к ИП плохая идея в 2021 - мобильники постоянно скачат между вайфай и 4г

Comment: @RomanKonoval а ещё несколько разных пользователей могут иметь один и тот же IP (спасибо провайдерским NAT, проксям и VPN)

Comment: динамический ИП не проблема, а вот роуминг в другого провайдера - беда.

Comment: @andreymal так можно сделать его одноразовым - написать мидлваре которое будет в куки при каждом запросе прописывать новый временный ключ.

Comment: Хм, в такой схеме серьёзных изъянов беглым взглядом уже не вижу

Comment: В разное время можно будет пользоваться тем самым ключом.

Comment: @RomanKonoval постоянный вылет ключа мотивирует не делиться им

Comment: Зависит от приложения. Если схема работы такая, что не нужно постоянно им пользоваться, то это не такая уж и проблема. Можно сделать периодические запросы на сервер, чтоб временный ключ обновлялся часто. Тогда это сделает пользование еще более проблематичным для щедрых.

Comment: @eri если сильно заморочиться, можно написать проксю, которая будет в себе держать временный ключ и через себя давать доступ неограниченному числу пользователей) Но тут уже от задачи автора зависит, насколько критична для него возможность создания такой прокси

Comment: @andreymal а давай изобретем TLS заново! на стороне js получаем новый временный расшифровав его по старому ключу с контролем последовательности.

Comment: @RomanKonoval веб-приложением скорее всего будут пользоваться постоянно

Comment: @eri а что мешает реализовать расшифровку и контроль последовательности в проксе? Ну а сторону js соответственно можно пропатчить для получения расшифрованных данных из прокси. // Кажется, такими темпами мы дойдём до такого наслоения шифрований всего подряд, что потенциальному взломщику расшифровывать всё это станет просто нерентабельно)

Comment: он тогда просто выкачает весь сайт с одного аккаунта и захостит зеркало))

Comment: @eri а если вообще забыть про ключ доступа, а сделать какую нибудь платную подписку или что-то вроде того ? и как лучше реализовать это ?

Comment: подписка на что будет активироваться? на пользователя? так логин пароль тоже можно раздать друзьям.

Comment: @eri та тоже вот уже подумал и понял, что так и будет) ну тогда, можно подробнее пожалуйста по поводу временного ключа и всего этого, а то я как-то не до конца понимаю механизм, если здесь не удобно писать, могу дать телеграм свой, если здесь удобно, то могу я задать несколько вопросов ?

Comment: @eri а как тогда работают многие сервисы с платным доступом ? ведь тогда получается, что такой механизм, когда можно поделится с друзьями работает везде ?